# Multi-file report showing Bibliography heading twice

Tags: bibliographies, multiple-files

I am using a multi-file document calling my content, including a bibliography.

The bibliography is created with a title page containing just the heading `Bibliography`, followed by the bibliography itself, with the same title at the start.

I do not want this. I want it to follow the same pattern as throughout the rest of the document, where each file is called with the heading at the start of the content, as seen on the MWE below in the section `Main'.

My MWE has four files:

`mwe.tex` (master), `main.tex`, `bibliography-test.tex`, `test.bib` (not included here).

**mwe.tex**:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{natbib,url}
\bibpunct{(}{)}{;}{a}{ }{,}
\DeclareUrlCommand\url{\def\UrlLeft{}\def\UrlRight{}\urlstyle{rm}}

\begin{document}

\include{main}
\include{bibliography-test}

\end{document}
```

**main.tex**:

```
\chapter*{Main}

This is a citation \citep{test01}.
\lipsum[5]
```

**bibliography-test.tex**:

```
\chapter*{Bibliography}

\bibliographystyle{myapalike-url}
\bibliography{\string~/my-location}
```

Comment: `\string~/my-location` looks weird. And is `myapalike-url` a generally known style? I can't compile the 'mwe' with `\bibpunct` etc.

Comment: that string is false as the location is on my computer and therefore won't load on yours. I amended apalike-url slightly and renamed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The string `Bibliography` appears twice since `\chapter*{Bibliography}` and `\bibliography{...}` do this -- The `\chapter*{Bibliography}` isn't necessary (or wrong here) since `\bibliography` already provides the heading!

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\begin{filecontents}{mymain.tex}

\chapter*{Main}
This is a citation \citep{Lam94}.
\lipsum[5]
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{bibliography-test.tex}

\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{biblio}
\end{filecontents}


\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{natbib,url}
%\bibpunct{(}{)}{;}{a}{ }{,}
\DeclareUrlCommand\url{\def\UrlLeft{}\def\UrlRight{}\urlstyle{rm}}

\begin{document}
\cite{Lam94}

\include{mymain}
\include{bibliography-test}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I was thinking this just after I posted. I've tested in my real document and it works. Thanks!